# Find Nearest Cities in US based on Zip code

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nearest Zip Code Search using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922195/nearest-zip-code-search-using-asp-net)

I need to find nearest cities on the base of Zip code and radius in US. Can any one give me idea or database, API related to this?

Comment: did you try Google?  also, this is a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6922195/418613

Answer (score 0):

Try the Google map API? You could definitely determine closest cities to a ZIP code using it.

Comment: can you please give me any link for this..

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/

Comment: Just be aware of Google's TOS so you don't take a wasted path as others have sometimes done unknowingly. Specifically: "Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited." see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/